# How to identify response contenttype in Zuul filter?

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, httpresponse, netflix-zuul

I have created one filter in zuul service.

I am able to get the response status but I am not able to get the response contenttype.

Code:

```
public class UserEventFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = ctx.getResponse();
        System.out.println("response status:" + response.getStatus());
        System.out.println("response status:" + ctx.getResponseStatusCode());
        System.out.println("response content type:" + response.getContentType());

        try (final InputStream responseDataStream = ctx.getResponseDataStream()) {
            final String responseData = CharStreams
                    .toString(new InputStreamReader(responseDataStream, Constants.ENCODING_UTF_8));
            ctx.setResponseBody(responseData);
            System.out.println("responseData:"+responseData);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

}
```

response content type is giving null.

What I want to do is, I have to get the response body for all responses except if it is "application/octet-stream".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
List<Pair<String, String>> headers = context.getZuulResponseHeaders();
```

Than find content type there. You should override filterType method:

```
@Override
public String filterType() {
   return POST_TYPE;
}
```

that is POST filter, if you want response I guess you are using post filter.